# What settings do I need to apply so I can ping a device behind a second router?

Tags: router, ping

I am a machine on 192.168.1.10 behind a router 192.168.1.254

I want to ping a device 192.168.16.250 but I can't, but the second router 192.168.16.254 can ping it.

I can ping the second router 192.168.16.254.

The two Draytek routers are connected via a Lan to Lan VPN.

VPN configurations of these routers are below in case it's here I need to make changes.

Router 192.168.1.254:

[image]

Router 192.168.16.254:

[image]

My knowledge is limited in this field.

What settings do I need to apply so I can ping a device behind a second router?

Do I need to bridge, tunnel or something else so I can ping devices behind this second router?

Comment: Can you ping from router to router?

Comment: Yes, Everything can ping each other apart from me pinging the device on the other side 192.168.16.250

Comment: Does 192.168.16.250 have a route to 192.168.1.0/24?

Comment: I don't think so - that is the thing I need to do I think. Where do I add that entry?

Comment: I've sorted it - I added the route correctly. Thank you